# Fetch Jenkins groovy script via SCM with a proxy

Tags: jenkins, networking, groovy, proxy, jenkins-pipeline

As the title says, I need to fetch a groovy script from a remote Gitlab instance that is behind a proxy.

I am trying to do it in the pipeline configuration (pipeline tab, 'Pipeline script from SCM'), but there is no option to use a proxy.

I have the right credentials and access (it's a service account btw).

Comment: Have you checked this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy#:~:text=You%20can%20configure%20the%20proxy,preferred%20over%20setting%20JVM%20properties.&text=If%20the%20proxy%20server%20requires,name%20of%20the%20user%20here.&text=If%20the%20proxy%20server%20requires%20authentication%2C%20enter%20the%20password%20here.